# Powershell fails to load DLL because manifest is missing

Tags: powershell, dll

These statements:

```
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\MvxAPI\MvxSockx64.dll")
```

Generate:

```
True

Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)
At C:\GitRepo\PowerShellScripts\ApiDllTest.ps1:11 char:1
+ [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\MvxAPI\MvxSockx64.dll")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException
```

From a PowerShell program I've written, I am trying to send transactions to the ERP system (Infor's M3) via a DLL for APIs.  The DLL is provided by the manufacture.  Since I am not a system admin but just a nerd supporting the ERP system, I'm clueless as to what I'm doing and have gotten this far with Google but can't get any further.  Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Add-Type -Path "C:\MvxAPI\MvxSockx64.dll"` yet?

Comment: Yes, with the same results.

Comment: @RickInGarland did you fix that issue? I am facing similar issue when try to load "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ServiceInterop.dll"?

Comment: @RickInGarland, did you fix that issues , same error with me also :(

Comment: We stopped using this process over a year ago so my memory is very fuzzy.  In looking at the psm1 to load the DLL, the only difference between what was posted and the code is that the creation was assigned to a variable: $M3Api = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\MvxAPI\MvxSockNx64.dll")

Comment: See remarks at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile?view=net-6.0&force_isolation=true